# Setting the background for Navigation View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I added the `Navigation View Controller` in storyboard and connected it to each `ViewController`.

I then created the class:

```
@interface NavigationViewController : UINavigationController
```

In the implementation I have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:@"#F40116" alpha:1.0];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

I tried to change background for `navigationBar` to Red in all ViewControllers - but background is still white. How can I make them all Red?

Comment: is your implementation for `colorWithHex:` correct? Because that's not a UIKit method.. Also, try using a breakpoint to confirm that you are actually implementing the subclass..

Comment: is the method colorWIthHex called ? You shouldn't use navigationCOntroller  reference in a NAvigationController subclass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to change the color of the navigationBar of the navigationController of your navigationController.

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:@"#F40116" alpha:1.0];
   self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Make sure you set `UINavigationController` class to your's custom controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make all visual changes on viewWillAppear

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

this should work for you.